# Неблокирующая попытка захвата монитора объекта

Tags: java

Пишу тестовое задание, в котором нужно написать небольшой ин-мемори транзакционный движок. Подразумевается, что в транзакции может участвовать несколько объектов, и нужно *попробовать* взять локи на все объекты, участвующие в транзакции (соответствующий метод у обычного лока - `Lock.tryLock()`), а в случае провала - откатиться и запустить всё сначала. Отсюда вопрос: есть ли в Java механизм, легальный или полулегальный (Unsafe и подобные извороты), позволяющий попробовать захватить монитор объекта и немедленно вернуться с boolean-результатом?

Comment: За `Unsafe` в наше время могут начать бить :) А легальный - это как раз `tryLock`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev речь про монитор объекта

Comment: Придётся в нужных классах объявить поле для хранения блокировки, иначе никак. Тем более, что Брайан Гетц в "Java Concurrency in Practice" как раз советует явно объявлять блокировки и инкапсулировать их, а не использовать мониторы объектов.